# instantiate capybara browser and set a proxy

Tags: ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

Following [this documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara-webkit/0.12.1/Capybara/Driver/Webkit/Browser#initialize-instance_method) I'm trying to instantiate a capybara browser and set a proxy

```
b = Capybara::Driver::Webkit::Browser.new
b.set_proxy :host => 'localhost', :port => 8888
```

Unfortunately the documentation is out of date and I can't find the new right way to do it. I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Capybara::Driver::Webkit::Browser
```

Comment: Do you want to run tests in Firefox? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

```
page.driver.browser.set_proxy :host => 'localhost', :port => 8888
```

Comment: page.driver.browser.set_proxy

NoMethodError: undefined method `set_proxy' for #<Capybara::Poltergeist::Browser