# Using capybara/webkit with a proxy?

Tags: ruby, proxy, webkit, capybara

I'm using capybara/webkit to emulate a browser, but I don’t know how to specify a proxy to use in the code:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/webkit'
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.current_driver = :webkit
include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.app_host = "http://test.com"
page.driver.allow_url("*")
visit('/')

# set_proxy('12.13.14.15', '4521')
```

Can anyone advise?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
page.driver.browser.set_proxy :host => 'localhost', :port => 8888
```

This is in reference to the StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339993/instantiate-capybara-browser-and-set-a-proxy)

Comment: undefined method `set_proxy' for ... :(

Comment: page.driver.browser.set_proxy

NoMethodError: undefined method `set_proxy' for #<Capybara::Poltergeist::Browser