# Capybara proxy turn on/off while testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, capybara, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using capybara, selenium and geckodriver.

I know that we can configure selenium to launch Firefox with a proxy using a code such as below:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(http: "127.0.0.1:9999", ssl: "127.0.0.1:9999")

  desired_caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox({
      firefox_profile: "default",
      proxy: proxy
    })
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :firefox, :desired_capabilities => desired_caps})
end

Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
@session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
```

This starts a Firefox instance with the proxy already configured.

Is there a way to turn on/off the proxy after Capybara has started its tests? (ie: I visit url `www.xyz.com` with proxy. And then, without closing the firefox instance, turn off the proxy, and visit `www.abc.com`. After that, turn on the proxy and visit `www.123.com`)

I saw an SO answer that is very close to what I am looking for, [instantiate capybara browser and set a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339993/instantiate-capybara-browser-and-set-a-proxy), but comments show that it no longer works.

Refs: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings